# Getting build history from jenkins from rest service

Tags: angular, rest, jenkins

Presently i am developing a angular application which shows the data of the builds from jenkins. So how to get that data from jenkins as a rest service.present i am using http://YOUR_JENKINS:8080/job/YOUR_JOB/api/xml?%20tree=jobs[name]{0,10}. but i am getting 403 unautharized. please can anybody help me in this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the jenkins user token in-order to make the rest call to jenkins api.

For csrf / crumb issues.
Need to get crumb from Jenkins using below command

wget -q --auth-no-challenge --user admin --password admin --output-document - 'http://192.168.99.20:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)'

This will return crumb value, then add this to Jenkins rest API

curl -I -X POST http://admin:85703fb68927f04968630e192e4927cb@192.168.99.20:8080/job/Football/build -H "Jenkins-Crumb:44e7033af70da95a47403c3bed5c10f8"

Below link explains in-detail
http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/jnrg/running-jenkins-build-via-command-line

Comment: but i am getting "Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request" when tried as above link.